# Azure IOT hub with S1:Stander Tier will charge for whole month if I use for 8hrs and delete it

Tags: azure, iot

I am using Azure Pay As You Go subscription. I wanted to create Azure IOT hub with S1:Stander Tier. Cost per month is :1652.41 INR. If I use it for 8 hrs for trying some example and delete the that create IOT hub, will it charge 1652.41 INR Or hourly or daily basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered in the FAQ at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/iot-hub/

The relevant section for these standing charges are:

> **How does billing work for the IoT Hub service?**
>
> The consumption of IoT Hub units is **measured on a daily basis**, and the billing is generated on a monthly basis. Customers are billed based on the number of IoT Hub units that have been consumed during the month.
>
> **Is the billing prorated if I purchase an additional IoT Hub unit mid-month?**
>
> You can choose to increase the number of IoT Hub units purchased at any time. If you sign up for the service mid-month, your monthly bill will be pro-rated based on the number of days remaining in the month. (**For the purpose of the IoT Hub service, a month is defined as 31 days**). If you increase the number of units of IoT Hub mid-month, your monthly bill will be based on the number of units available for each day during the month.

So for your example of 8 hours use in a single day will be measured as the monthly rate divided by 31.